# SCSS: Select where no parent has class

Tags: css, sass

I have hit a use case where I would like to only apply styling to an element if none of its parents has a specific class.

```
<body>
   <h2>I should have styles</h2>
   <div class="myClass"> 
      <h1>I should have styles</h1>
      <h2>I should not have styles</h2>
      <div>
         <h2>I should not have styles</h2>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div> 
      <h2>I should have styles</h2>
   </div>
</body>
```

I have tried a few things, none of them pretty or functional.

```
*:not(.myClass) h2{
   ...
}
```

This clearly doesn't work because there will almost be a parent that doesn't have the class.

```
*:not(.myClass) > h2{
   ...
}
```

This is not better. It only targets the first parent of the element we want to style.

```
*:not(.myClass){
  & > *:not(.myClass){
    & > *:not(.myClass){
      & > *:not(.myClass){
        & > *:not(.myClass){
          & > h2{
            ...
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will sort of work. It selects correctly if no parents in 5 levels has the class, but if the class is one parent further up, it breaks, and it is not the prettiest thing in the world.

But is there a simpler solution for "Apply this style if no parent has class X"?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know exactly what the solution for you is without seeing more of your infrastructure, but there is a potential solution:

```css
h2:not(.myClass *),
h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h2>I should have styles</h2>
  <div class="myClass">
    <h1>I should have styles</h1>
    <h2>I should not have styles</h2>
    <div>
      <h2>I should not have styles</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>I should have styles</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```